# Hibernate HQL casting: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Enum

Tags: java, hibernate

I am getting this problem:

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Enum
```

When I try this *HQL*:

```
...
query = em.createQuery("SELECT object from Entity object where object.column = ?");
query.setParameter(1, "X");
return query.getResultList();
```

Where in DB the *type* is a *Varchar2(x)* with a check constraint and the variable in the entity is defined with *Enum* using the tag @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING):

```
public enum ColumnEnum {
    X, Y;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `query.setParameter(1, TypeEnum.X);` ?

Comment: I have tried this too, but the received error is the same

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If the field is defined as an enum, you must pass an enum as parameter:

```
query.setParameter(1, TypeEnum.X);
```

And let Hibernate use the mapping to transform the parameter into a String (if `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` is uses) or into an int (if `@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)` is used).

Answer (score 3):

**using following annotation**

```
@Enumerated (value = EnumType.STRING)
```

OR

```
Query q = session.createQuery(from Comment c where c.rating = :rating);
q.setParameter(rating,
               Rating.LOW,
               Hibernate.custom(RatingUserType.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example, with two ways.

- First way is to explicitly provide enum
- And a second, more convenient, is to provide a string representation, if a field is enumerated as sring.

---

```
    public Optional<AffectedAsset> getByEntityId(Long entityId, String assetType) {
    String hql = "FROM AffectedAsset a WHERE a.entityId = :entityId "
            + "                        AND a.type = :assetType "
            + "   ORDER BY id DESC";
    Query query = getSession().createQuery( hql );
    query.setLong( "entityId", entityId );
    // little bit cumbersome : 
    // query.setParameter( "assetType", AffectedAsset.Type.valueOf( assetType.toUpperCase() ) );
    // my preferred way :
    query.setString( "assetType", assetType.toUpperCase() );
    query.setReadOnly( true );
    query.setMaxResults( 1 );

    AffectedAsset res = (AffectedAsset) query.uniqueResult();
    return Optional.ofNullable( res );
}
```